# HTML, CSS, flask_wtf how to change form field locations

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first webapp. I need a simple form for the user to submit a few values. I got it working, but I would like the data entry fields to be on a row instead of in a column.

You can see bootstrap used in the snippets below. I don't think that is involved because the fields render in the same locations without using it.

base.html:

```html
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
...
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
...
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
...
        {# application content needs to be provided in the app_content block #}
        {% block app_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, IPAddress, NumberRange, length

class SnmpQueryForm(FlaskForm):
    ip = StringField('IP Address', validators=[IPAddress()])
    mask = IntegerField('Mask bits',
                         validators=[DataRequired(),
                         NumberRange(22, 32)]
                       )
    snmpcmstr = StringField('Community String',
                            validators=[DataRequired(),
                            length(max=20)]
                           )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit Query')
```

template.html:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>Enter SNMP Query Information</h1>
    <form action="", method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        ...
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I would like the three fields to be on the same line (in the same row). Any suggestions?

Thank you

Just to add the solution I used for posterity:

All I had to do was change Lakindu's POC code to:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    {{wtf.form_field(form.ip, class="form-control", placeholder="Enter IP") }}
  </div>
</div>
```

for each input field and add:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="input submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>  
</div>
```

for the submit button.

Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: use col-md-4 for each input element in order to get into same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof of concept of what you trying to achieve. 
You can use `col-md-4` in a `row` and a `container` class in order to get three input fields to a single row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form action="" , method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>IP address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Mask bits</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Community string</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to show how I used my code based on your example.